# Jquery load.() issue

Tags: jquery

I'm loading pages asynchronously with jQuery's load function. It loads all external content perfectly fine except when I try to embed a link from pastie.org, like this:

```
<script src='http://pastie.org/3644003.js'></script>
```

When I hardcode this into the main site it works, however, as soon as I load it via .load() it stays blank.

I'm guessing this is some kind of limitation of Ajax.
Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: perhaps instead of load() use full .ajax() options with datatype set to script

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of .load at http://api.jquery.com/load/

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the load function try using the 
`$.getScript('http://pastie.org/3644003.js')` function

Answer (score 0):

if u want to exec only script..

use

```
$.getScript('url');
```